# Format the method docu into an array (regex/php)

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use REGEX to format the method documentation of a specific class to make it available to others as a documentation. The docu looks something like this:

```
/**
 * Description description description
 * @access public
 * @GET string
 * [{ "name":"number","type":"string","description":"ASDASDASDAD" },{ "name":"number","type":"string","description":"ASDASDASDAD" }]
 * @POST string
 * [{ "name":"number","type":"string","description":"ASDASDASDAD" }]
 * @RESPONSE type
 * [{ "name":"number","type":"string","description":"ASDASDASDAD" }]
 */
```

I want to build an associative array from this structure like:

```
"description" => "Description description description"
"access" => "public"
"get" => array ( "type" => "string", "json" => "[{ "name":"number","type":"string","description":"ASDASDASDAD" }]"
```

and so on. My current approach was getting the whole thing and then explode it on the @. This gave me everything different array parts, but since I'm not very experienced in REGEX all my efforts to filter from there failed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look for Annotation Parser there are enough already..Take a look at doctrine and/or symfony for example - https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationReader.php

Comment: Don't use regex, use the [PHP tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php).... but use `@see` or `@inherit(doc)` in your docblocks for classes that extend

Comment: could you point me in the right direction how i can achieve this with tokens? i looked into the php docu but there arent really any helpful examples